# Oracle SQL regexp_substr programming issue

Tags: sql, oracle

Can anyone help me solve this? I'm a bit of a newbie in programming and I'm looking at using REGEXP_SUBSTR in my query. I have a large file and I need to use only certain parts.

I want to convert this: Stuart, Martin E (Martin.Stuart@canadanotes.ca)  to this: Martin.Stuart@canadanotes.ca

I'm using regexp_substr and have got it to display everything apart but I have an annoying bracket on the end of the email address I need to get rid of.  Can anyone help please?

```
SELECT regexp_substr ('Stuart, Martin G (Martin.Stuart@canadanotes.ca)', '[^("]+',1,2)
FROM dual;

REGEXP_SUBSTR('STUART,MARTING(
------------------------------
Martin.Stuart@canadanotes.ca)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select regexp_substr ('Stuart, Martin G (Martin.Stuart@canadanotes.ca)', '[^)("]+',1,2) from dual;
```

Just add the closing bracket inside [^]

Answer (score 0):

```
 select regexp_substr ('Stuart, Martin G (Martin.Stuart@canadanotes.ca)', '[^()]+',1,2) from dual;
```

works fine. And why are using the literal " in the expression.